# MySQL accessing a json array

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Need help figuring out syntax for an MySQL query.

I have a table called "activegames" with a column called "gameresults"

inside game results I have this JSON data.

```
{
    "gameID": "7c3b0c36-c18e",
    "scores": [
        {
            "id": "14916624",
            "score": 40
        },
        {
            "id": "1234565",
            "score": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried many things and have read a lot of documentation but I cannot figure how to select the data inside scores and say get each id or each score.

Can anyone help me figure out the syntax for the query.

EDIT: I also need to figure out how I can search the "scores" array to see if any of the elements has a specific id'

something like `SELECT gameresults WHERE scores CONTAINS ID "1234565"`

basically I have a php script that I need to pass an id to the query and search the whole "activegames" table to see if any of the "gameresults" has a "scores" array containing that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [json_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to convert your json into rows :

```
SELECT *
     FROM
       activegames, JSON_TABLE(
         gameresults,
         "$.scores[*]"
         COLUMNS(
           id INT PATH "$.id",
           score INT PATH "$.score"
         )
       ) data
where id = 14916624
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6nKD7GHtg2z1Jx96v71AJ/0)

Comment: Thanks so much. I was almost there but was getting confused by the examples in the documentation. I've got it working now.